# Get details for selected establishment on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocomplete

There's quite a few questions on this, and documentation available, however it seems that I can't find the solution for the use case I'm trying to solve.

What I'd like to do:

- Have a Google Map with a search box so a user can search for a location (a city of more specific a point of interest). This is something that I can do.
- When a user searches for a location, *no* marker is placed, the map only zooms in on the location
- User can click on an establishment from the [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places)
- When that place is clicked, I'd like to get details from this place

So it's basically extending [the places autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) with the last bullet mentioned

-or-

using the [geocomplete library](http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/), more specifically [the form example](http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/examples/form.html), because it already gives all the details needed that are listed below. The thing I'm missing is how to not place a marker on search, and how to get details from an establishment only when the users clicks on it.

The details that I would like to get from the establishment when clicked, which are directly available through geocomplete, are:

- Name
- Formatted address (see geocomplete form example)
- URL to Google Maps (like: https://maps.google.com/?cid=16742034748962857918)
- Latitude
- Longitude
- Website

**UPDATE**

With the geocomplete library you can bind a click event, like so:

```
$("#geocomplete_input_field").bind("geocode:click", function(event, latLng){
  $("input[name=lat]").val(latLng.lat());
  $("input[name=lng]").val(latLng.lng());
});
```

So with that we get the latitude and longitude. But can you also get the formatted_address, name, and url as happens in the form example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you don't need any external library to accomplish this. Since everything is already done (codes), all you need to do is just add a 'POI Click Event'. It listens for the click event on a POI icon and then uses the placeId for anything you wanted to achieve. In your case you wanted to acquire these: name, formatted_addres, url, lat, lng, and website.

In the example that I will provide you, I just created a constructor 'ClickEventHandler'. You can check **[POI Click](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-poi)** for sample and documentation.

```
  var ClickEventHandler = function(map, origin) {
    this.origin = origin;
    this.map = map;
    this.placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    this.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    // Listen for clicks on the map.
    this.map.addListener('click', this.handleClick.bind(this));
  };
```

Then, create a new instance inside your init() function and supply the arguments: map and origin.

```
var clickHandler = new ClickEventHandler(map, {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195});
```

In the 'ClickEventHandler' object, create a prototype 'getPlaceInformation' that accepts an argument 'placeid'. You need to use **[Google Maps Javascript API Place Details](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-details)** in this section. Inside Google Maps Javascript API Place Details **getDetails** method, you will use the placeid you supplied as argument coming from the previous function (getPlaceInformation) you created. **getDetails** method needs 2 arguments: place and status. This method gets all the details from the placeid you supplied. Once you get the **status === 'OK'**, it will return to you data that you are expecting.

```
ClickEventHandler.prototype.getPlaceInformation = function(placeId) {  
   this.placesService.getDetails({placeId: placeId}, function(place, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {         
      }
   });
};
```

Working example below (with details in infowindow and input elements value supplied from the POI):

```js
      // This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
      // feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
      // pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

      function initAutocomplete() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
          zoom: 13,
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });

        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
          searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });

        
        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
        // more details for that place.
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
          var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

          if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
          }

          // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          places.forEach(function(place) {
            if (!place.geometry) {
              console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
              return;
            }
            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              // Only geocodes have viewport.
              bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
              bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
          });
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
        var clickHandler = new ClickEventHandler(map, {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195});
      }
      var ClickEventHandler = function(map, origin) {
        this.origin = origin;
        this.map = map;
        this.placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        this.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        // Listen for clicks on the map.
        this.map.addListener('click', this.handleClick.bind(this));
      }; 

      ClickEventHandler.prototype.getPlaceInformation = function(placeId) {
        var me = this;     
        this.placesService.getDetails({placeId: placeId}, function(place, status) {
          me.infowindow.close();
          if (status === 'OK') {
            var inputNames = [ 'name', 'formatted_address', 'url',  'website' ];
            for ( var val in inputNames ) {
               document.getElementById(inputNames[val]).value = place[inputNames[val]];
            }
            document.getElementById('lat').value = place.geometry.location.lat();
            document.getElementById('lng').value = place.geometry.location.lng();
            var template = '<div id="infoContent">';
            template += '<ul>';
            template += '<li><span>Name: </span>'+place.name+'</li>';
            template += '<li><span>Formatted address: </span>'+place.name+'</li>';
            template += '<li><span>Google Maps URL: </span><a href="'+place.url+'" target="_blank">'+place.url+'</a></li>';
            template += '<li><span>Latitude: </span>'+place.geometry.location.lat()+'</li>';
            template += '<li><span>Longitude: </span>'+place.geometry.location.lng()+'</li>';
            template += '<li><span>Website: </span><a href="'+place.website+'" target="_blank">'+place.website+'</a></li>';
            template += '</ul>';
            me.infowindow.setContent(template);
            me.infowindow.setPosition(place.geometry.location);           
            me.infowindow.open(me.map);            
          }
        });
      };  

      ClickEventHandler.prototype.handleClick = function(event) {
        //console.log('You clicked on: ' + event.latLng);
        // If the event has a placeId, use it.
        if (event.placeId) {
            //console.log('You clicked on place:' + event.placeId);
          // Calling e.stop() on the event prevents the default info window from
          // showing.
          // If you call stop here when there is no placeId you will prevent some
          // other map click event handlers from receiving the event.
          event.stop();
          this.getPlaceInformation(event.placeId);
        }
      };
```

```css
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #description {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }

      .pac-card {
        margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
      }

      #pac-container {
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        margin-right: 12px;
      }

      .pac-controls {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px 11px;
      }

      .pac-controls label {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }

      #pac-input {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-left: 12px;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 400px;
      }

      #pac-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
      }

      #title {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        font-size: 25px;
        font-weight: 500;
        padding: 6px 12px;
      }
      #target {
        width: 345px;
      }
      #infoContent {
        width:100%;
        float:left;
        overflow:hidden;
        display:block;
      }
      #infoContent > ul {
        width:100%;
        float:left;
        overflow:hidden;
        display:block;
      }
      #infoContent > ul > li {
        width:100%;
        float:left;
        overflow:hidden;
        clear:both;
        font-size:12px;
      }
      #infoContent > ul > li span {
        font-weight:bold;
      }
      #infoContent > ul > li a {
        text-decoration:none;
      }
      #myForm {
        width:100%;
        float:left;
        overflow:hidden;
        display:block;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        padding: 10xp;
      }
      #myForm fieldset {
        display:block;
        clear:both;
        float:left;
        border:none;
      }
      #myForm fieldset label {
        width:100%;
        float:left;
        overflow:hidden;
        display:block;
        clear:both;
        line-height:24px;
      }
      #myForm fieldset input {
        width: 100%;
        float:left;
        overflow:hidden
        display:block;
        clear:both;
        line-height: 24px;
        padding: 0 5px;
      }
```

```html
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <form id="myForm">
      <fieldset>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <label>Formatted address:</label>
        <input type="text" name="formatted_address" id="formatted_address" />
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <label>URL to Google Maps:</label>
        <input type="text" name="url" id="url" />
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <label>Latitude:</label>
        <input type="text" name="lat" id="lat" />
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <label>Longitude:</label>
        <input type="text" name="lng" id="lng" />
      </fieldset>
       <fieldset>
        <label>Website:</label>
        <input type="text" name="website" id="website" />
      </fieldset>     
    </form>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCzjs-bUR6iIl8yGLr60p6-zbdFtRpuXTQ&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
         async defer></script>
```

Hope it helps and happy coding!